# Cannot add a static librar to project(followed tutorials previously)

Tags: linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I'd like to use a custom library but I cannot add it to my Visual Studio Project. It is located here https://github.com/ousnius/nifly.

I used CMake to extract initial library package in which I've found .sln file and I used this to create a static library "nifly.lib".

In my project I added path to the library under  "Linker-General" section.
Then I added "Additional dependencies" - "nifly.lib".

Then I should be good to go but including files doesn't work. For instance this line doesn't compile

```
#include <NifFile.hpp>
E1696   cannot open source file "NifFile.hpp"
```

Even adding a line such as this doesn't compile

```
using namespace nifly;
E0725   name must be a namespace name
```

Library author says that his library is okay. Am I missing something? It's my first experience with linking libraries and unfortunately after following tutorials(which say the same thing) I cannot make it work. I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It's not the library that's the issue. It's the INCLUDE path to the .hpp file. You'll need to add that folder to the INCLUDE list.

Comment: I've just checked - the library is in "$(SolutionDir)" of the project which is included in "Additional Include Directories. Do I need to add it in the list somewhere else?